# Add image into html table dynamically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table

I'm trying to add an image into table dynamically but it doesn't happen...
also when I add an image into the cell there is an error message:

> Cannot get the inner content of because the contents are not literal.

```
        if (filteredFileList.Count != 0 && filteredFileList != null) {
            imgProduct.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath(@"/ysyp/Images/Products/") + filteredFileList[0].Name;
            rowCount = 1;
            columnCount = filteredFileList.Count;
            try {
                HtmlTable tbProductImage = new HtmlTable();
                HtmlTableRow trImageRow = new HtmlTableRow();
                for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                    if (filteredFileList.Count != 0) {
                        HtmlTableCell tdImageRow = new HtmlTableCell();
                        Image imageProduct = new Image();                       
                        imageProduct.ID = "img" + filteredFileList[j].Name.Substring(0, filteredFileList[j].Name.LastIndexOf("."));
                        imageProduct.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath(@"/ysyp/Images/Products/") + filteredFileList[j].Name;
                        tdImageRow.Controls.Add(imageProduct);
                        trImageRow.Controls.Add(tdImageRow);
                    }
                }

                tbProductImage.Controls.Add(trImageRow); // <<< ERROR HERE

                tdProduct.Controls.Add(tbProductImage);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                string msg = exc.Message;
            }
        }
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
HtmlTable tbProductImage = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTableRow trImageRow = new HtmlTableRow();
for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++)
{
    if (filteredFileList.Count != 0)
    {

        HtmlTableCell tdImageCell = new HtmlTableCell();
        Image imageProduct = new Image();
        imageProduct.ID = "id";
        imageProduct.ImageUrl = "url";
        tdImageCell.Controls.Add(imageProduct);
        trImageRow.Cells.Add(tdImageCell);
    }
}
tbProductImage.Rows.Add(trImageRow);
```

Comment: are you sure? I tested my code and it works for me. If it gives an error for you, I believe the error must lie outside of the code block in your question.

Comment: i know i wrote the same code another page it works but im trying to make works upside code... and i dont understand what the hell is happening....

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `Controls.Add`, use `Rows.Add` instead, try this:

```
tbProductImage.Rows.Add(trImageRow);
```

But I'm not sure if this will solve your problem.

Comment: thx but error is in line: tdImageRow.Controls.Add(imageProduct);
Cannot get inner content of because the contents are not literal. i dont understand

Comment: serim. Change your question if you are having the error there. You wrote that you are having error at tbProductImage.Controls.Add(trImageRow); You cannot add a tablerow as control to a table. If you seek help, be clear about your problem!

Comment: there is not an error, code is clear, i know because the same  code works clearly on another page...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tbProductImage.Rows.Add(trImageRow);
```

`tbProductImage` is an `HtmlTable`. If you want to add an `HtmlTableRow` to the table, you need to add it to the `Rows` collection. Adding it to the `Controls` collection will give you the error that you currently see. So changing your code from `Controls` to `Rows` should give you what you need.

The same thing applies for adding a cell to a row. A few lines above, you want to replace `trImageRow.Controls.Add(tdImageRow);` with `trImageRow.Cells.Add(tdImageRow);`

Comment: thx but error is in line: tdImageRow.Controls.Add(imageProduct); Cannot get inner content of because the contents are not literal. i dont understand

Comment: I added some more explanation, and a similar suggestion for fixing code above in the row where you are adding the cell to the row.

Comment: thx but ive already did it but my problem is not this , there is htmlcell innertext and innerhtml properties... my doesnt work because of them and i still dont know th reason

Answer (score 0):

Add a cell to the row, and then add a control to the cell.

We do this kind of thing...

```
Dim r As TableRow
    Dim c As TableCell
    Dim lit As Literal

    Me.displayTable.Rows.Clear()

    r = AddRow(Me.displayTable, 0)
    c = AddCell(r, 100)

    lit = New Literal
    lit.Text = "Thank you for registering your interest."
    c.Controls.Add(lit)
```

The Table, Row, and Cell objects are from the `System.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace, but they render as HTML tables.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You are trying to add the image to a `tablerow` (`TR`) this won't work because `TR`s can only contain `tablecells` (`TD`).</strike>
You are trying to add the row to the table directly instead of to the table's `Rows` collection:

The way to do it is:

1. Make a new row.
2. Make new cell.
3. Add image to new cell.
4. Add new cell to new row.
5. Add new row to table (via table's `Rows` connection)

EDIT: Sorry, my eyesight isn't what it was - old age and late nights :-(

I think your code goes off-road because you're not adding the row to the table's Rows collection:

<strike>tbProductImage.Controls.Add(trImageRow); // <<< ERROR HERE</strike>
    tbProductImage.Rows.Add(trImageRow);
    tdProduct.Controls.Add(tbProductImage);

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bewx260(v=VS.85).aspx